# upload to ftp asp.net

Tags: asp.net, upload, ftp, file-upload

Is it possible to upload a file directly into an ftp account folder with ASP.NET ?

E.g. I click on browse, select a file to upload and when I click "upload" button, It should save it directly to the folder on another web server located at somewhere else other then the server that is being used to upload.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question, you want to upload the file to another remote server (so it's not another server sitting on the same network as your web server)? In that case you can do a couple of different things. The easiest way is perhaps to start by making a regular file upload you your server, and then have your server send the file via FTP to the other remote server:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine("<path on your server", FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);
using(System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    webClient.UploadFile(
        New Uri("ftp://remoteserver/remotepath/" + FileUpload1.FileName), 
        localFile);
}
```

...or it might work doing it in one step:

```
using(System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    webClient.UploadData(
        New Uri("ftp://remoteserver/remotepath/" + FileUpload1.FileName), 
        FileUpload1.FileBytes);
}
```

(I din't try this code out, so there could be some errors in it...)

Update: I noticed that I was wrong in assuming that the UploadXXX methods of WebClient were static...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `WebClient` class to store the uploaded file to FTP (without saving it as a file on the server). Something like this:

```
string name = Path.GetFileName(UploadControl.FileName);
byte[] data = UploadControl.FileBytes;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
   client.UploadData("ftp://my.ftp.server.com/myfolder/" + name, data);
}
```

Comment: This definitely doesn't work for my ASP.NET web app. I wonder why this is such a popular solution when I can't even get it to work. So frustrating! >.<

Comment: @Chiramisu: There are several possible reasons why it doesn't work in your case, but the method does work under the right circumstances. It's just a matter of figuring out what's keeping it from working.

Comment: I'm surprised you responded to such an old thread, but thank you. I've been trying to successfully upload a file to FTP for days now. Would you be so kind as to take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744447/desperate-ftp-fileupload-wrong-client-path) on the matter?

Answer (score 4):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Example call : if (FtpUpload(FileUploadControl1, "ftp.my.com/somePathDir", @"user", "pass!", "domain"))
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file"></param>
    /// <param name="ftpServer"></param>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <param name="ftpPass"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool FtpUpload(FileUpload file, string ftpServer, string username, string ftpPass, string domainName = "")
    {
        // ftp://domain\user:password@ftpserver/url-path
        // If you are a member of a domain, then "ftp://domain-name\username:password@url-path" may fail because the backslash (\) is sent in as a literal character and Internet Explorer incorrectly looks for a file instead of parsing a Web address. Changing the backslash (\) in the domain-name\username to domainname%5Cusername works correctly.

        try
        {
            string ftpAddres;
            if (domainName != string.Empty)
                ftpAddres = "ftp://" + domainName + @"%5C" + username + ":" + ftpPass + "@" + ftpServer + "/" + file.FileName;
            else
                ftpAddres = "ftp://" + username + ":" + ftpPass + "@" + ftpServer + "/" + file.FileName;

            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                webClient.UploadData(new Uri(ftpAddres), file.FileBytes);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload it to an FTP directly from your HTML form. However, you can upload it to your ASP.NET application and then upload it to the FTP from there using [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(loband).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

First off the `@` sign is there to flag the string as a literal. it saves you having to escape characters like backslashes. e.g.

```
string path = "Z:\\Path\\To\\File.txt";
string path = @"Z:\Path\To\File.txt";
```

Secondly, if you only have FTP Access to the other server, then you can take, the `FileUpload.FileBytes` Property of the FileUpload control. That will give you a `byte[]` of the file contents.

From this you use the `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` & `System.Net.FtpWebResponse` to upload your file to the FTP Account.

Theres some sample code here in VB.NET but it should be easy enough for you to figure out

http://www.programmingforums.org/thread15954.html

**ORIG**

The file upload control will provide you with the File on your webserver.

It would be up to you, to copy/save that file then from the webserver to whatever server
you're FTP is hosted on.

Do you have a UNC Path/Mapped Drive shared out on your other server that you can save to.

The FileUpload Control has a `.SaveAs()` method so it's just a simple matter of

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
try
{
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"Z:\Path\On\Other\Server\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer.. Can you tell me what the @ sign is used for? and if I can use an IP address rather then a physical path as the web page will be on a different server than the server I will be uploading the files to.. e.g. fpt.mydomain.com/images  and in that case if this can be done, I will probably need to provide user credentials right? if so how?

Comment: The @ site creates a vertabum string, basically removing the need to escape \ as \\

Comment: For more information on verbatim strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(loband).aspx