# FTP Client uploads only 0KB files

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, ftp

I am having a small problem with my FTP client.
Choosing a file works, renaming that file with 4 variables works.
It's the upload that is causing me trouble.
Whenever a file is uploaded to the FTP server it says it is 0KB.

I am thinking of 2 possible problems:

Visual studio tells me that the variable `file` is used before it has been assigned a value, to make sure it isn't null i did the following.

```
Dim file As Byte()  

If (Not file Is Nothing) Then
            strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
            strz.Close()
            strz.Dispose()
            FileSystem.Rename(Filename, originalFile)
        End If
```

This Takes care of any possible Errors.

The second one is fName, same warning as with file, and I took care of it the same way.

another possibility is that my code just takes the 4 variables and makes that into a file and uploads it, hence the 0KB size....

Here's my code:

```
Dim Filename As String
    Dim originalFile As String

    Private Function enumerateCheckboxes(ByVal path As String)
        originalFile = path
        Dim fName As String
        For Each Control In Me.Controls
            If (TypeOf Control Is ComboBox AndAlso DirectCast(Control, ComboBox).SelectedIndex > -1) Then
                fName += CStr(Control.SelectedItem.Key) + "_"
            End If
        Next
        Try
            fName = path + fName.Substring(0, fName.Length - 1) + ".jpg"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox("Stack Trace: " & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
        Return fName
    End Function

    Public Function OpenDialog()
        Dim FD As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        FD.Title = "Selecteer een bestand"
        FD.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        FD.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        FD.FilterIndex = 2
        FD.RestoreDirectory = True

        If FD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim Filename As String = FD.FileName
            Filename = StrReverse(Filename)
            Filename = Mid(Filename, InStr(Filename, "\"), Len(Filename))
            Filename = StrReverse(Filename)
            MsgBox(enumerateCheckboxes(Filename))
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ip" & enumerateCheckboxes(Filename)), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
        request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
        request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        Dim file() As Byte

        Try
            Filename = OpenDialog()
            If (Not Filename Is Nothing) Then
                System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filename)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show("Stack Trace: " & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
        If (Not Filename Is Nothing) Then
            FileSystem.Rename(originalFile, Filename)
        End If
        Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        If (Not file Is Nothing) Then
            strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
            strz.Close()
            strz.Dispose()
            FileSystem.Rename(Filename, originalFile)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have looked at multiple threads with the same problem as me.
Threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744447/zero-size-files-uploaded-with-ftp-fileupload)
But i dont believe this applies to my problem.
If you would be so kind to explain what i did wrong and how i can fix and avoid this in the future, my debugging is still a bit rough...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is giving you that warning because you never assign anything to the `file` array. I think that on the line where you have:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filename)
```

You really meant to have:

```
file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Filename)
```

Comment: oké, I see where I went  wrong, but.. The files that are being  uploaded to my server are still 0Kb

Comment: I think you also need to call `request.GetResponse()` prior to disposing the stream.