# Upload a file to a ftp folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, ftp

After do some research I have come up relatively empty on this subject. What I am trying to do is basically upload a file (.jpeg) from an asp.net page when a user hits an upload button to our companys public website. The files are stored in a folder on the ftp site.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get started on this? I have the ftp credentials and I can logon and see the actual folder I need to upload too, I just need some direction. I have never worked with ftp through asp.net before.

Thanks!

Comment: go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838584/upload-to-ftp-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

The upload should be possible with *FtpWebRequest* class.

Usage details and examples of the *FtpWebRequest* class is available at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx

Also check whether the following site is useful:
http://nethelp.wikidot.com/ftpupload

Comment: I tried the link paabobo but that does not give me the option to login using the ftp credentials. Do you know how to fix this?